# jhipster does not cache the results of query

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, jhipster

I noticed that cache memory does not work. if you set

```
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.stat" level="DEBUG"/>
```

I have an entity of City which does not change regularly and the time to execute the query is almost 500 ms. What am i doing wrong. Also i set the entity of City to ehcache.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D16V0.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i believe that i fixed the problem. Into the implementation of service you have to add one line

```
@Override
**@Cacheable( "com.ppc.ptol2.domain.City" )**
@Transactional( readOnly = true )
public List<City> findAll() {
    log.debug("Request to get all City");
    return cityRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between the Hibernate 2nd level cache (configured by default in JHipster) and the Spring cache abstraction (which you use here), which you need to configure using the Cacheable annotation. They serve different purposes, and both use ehcache